# MVVMCross inactive page after click

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have a question? Application is implemented in MVVMCross with Xamarin.Forms. I have 3 views. I use TollbarItem for running next pages. If I run it under VisualStudio in Release or Debug mode then all works corectly. If I run it on different phones with Android (ver 8-9) I have problem after back from any next page. This page where I've clicked page becomes inactive :-(

I noticed, when I run few times on first page any options, the second view is sometimes active.

I've installed a lot of different versions of Xamarin.Forms from 2.3... to 4.5...., it's the same.

Could you help me? Thank's in advance :-)

If you need more codes tell me please. 
My code the first viewmodel from I navigate to the next view:

```
public ICommand ShowSettingsPageCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(() => RunShowSettingsPageCommand());

public ICommand ShowHelpPageCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(() => RunShowHelpPageCommand());

public async Task RunShowHelpPageCommand()
{
    await navigationService.Navigate<HelpViewModel>();
}

public async Task RunShowSettingsPageCommand()
{
    await navigationService.Navigate<SettingsViewModel>();
}
```

Before I've used this form too (but it wasn't working too):

```
public ICommand ShowSettingsPageCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(() => navigationService.Navigate<SettingsViewModel>());
```

I tried changed my code as below (I've pasted more lines):

//public ICommand ShowSettingsPageCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(() => RunShowSettingsPageCommand());
            public ICommand ShowSettingsPageCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(RunShowSettingsPageCommand);

//public ICommand ShowHelpPageCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(() => RunShowHelpPageCommand());
            public ICommand ShowHelpPageCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(RunShowHelpPageCommand);

```
        public ICommand OnChangeClicked => new Command(()=>RunChangeClicked());

        public ICommand OnEyeClicked => new Command(()=>RunOnEyeClicked());

        public ICommand OnPowerClicked => new Command(()=> RunOnPowerClicked());

        public ICommand OnCopyToClipboardClicked => new Command((() => RunOnCopyToClipboardClicked()));

        public ICommand OnShareClicked => new Command((() => RunOnShareClicked()));

        public async Task RunShowHelpPageCommand()
        {
            await navigationService.Navigate<HelpViewModel>();
        }

        public async Task RunShowSettingsPageCommand()
        {
            await navigationService.Navigate<SettingsViewModel>();
        }


        public async Task RunOnShareClicked()
        {

            await Task.Run(() => Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
            {
                Text = YourWordCrypted,
                Title = "Wygenerowano w Koderek: "
            }));
        }

        public async void RunOnCopyToClipboardClicked()
        {
            await Clipboard.SetTextAsync(YourWordCrypted);
        }


        public void RunOnPowerClicked()
        {
            YourWord=String.Empty;
        }


        public void RunOnEyeClicked()
        {
            IsHideYourWord =!IsHideYourWord;
        }


        public void RunChangeClicked()
        {
            YourWord = YourWordCrypted;
        }



        public string RunCodeOn()
        {
            return CaesarSolve();
        }
```

Unfortunately, the problem still ocurs...

Comment: Show us some code here. You can check the output window for any logs. Or since its only 3 pages, Just comment out codes in blocks and find which one causes it. There can be many reasons for this mostly from your description `await` `async` usage could have caused it.

Comment: I've added code but if you need more something tell me please. I've not noticed any problems until I send app to phone and run it on phone. I've not found this topic on forum

Comment: You aren't awaiting the `RunShowSettingsPageCommand` try removing the `() =>` before `RunShowSettingsPageCommand`. Just a guess. Have you tried it?

Comment: If I do as you wrote: public ICommand ShowSettingsPageCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(RunShowSettingsPageCommand()); I have underlined in red RunShowSettingsPageCommand()

Comment: It should be `MvxAsyncCommand(RunShowSettingsPageCommand)`

Comment: Thanks. I made this, but the problem still ocurs. I've added new information about this in my question above.

Comment: There could be lots of reason. Try commenting code blocks and check. Since you specify error to be occurring in Android 8-9, this could mostly be due to UI code

Comment: I've just noticed any dependence... I switched on navigating to next page by any image on first page. If I click this image and I go to the next page and 
 back, every next navigation by ToolbarItem or image to every next page and back works correctly. From youur point of view, it's possible that problem is located in ToolbarItem? It indicates that navigation using only image (not ToolbarItem) should work correctly.?